# What's the 'fixed constant nature of sensible things'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Aristotle makes the claim that, "the fact that a thing is itself" allows for "a fixed constant nature of sensible things"

Does it mean:

- sensible things **look like** fixed and constant, or
- sensible things **are** fixed and constant?

What does *nature* mean?

Comment: Could we get a little more context, please?

Comment: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Metaphysics/Book_VII#Part_17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally, that the nature of "things", at least, sensible things, is fixed and constant. A thing is itself, reflexively, and we can proceed from that point without having to reexamine the nature of it as we draw inferences from it.

Here's Wikipedia's take: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_identity

Think about Descartes' famous "I think, therefore I am". What he's saying there is, because I am able to contemplate my own existence, I can reasonably assume my own existence. Without that assumption, nothing real can be inferred, and it's all just college dorm room B.S. Instead, a thing is itself, and that allows for a fixed, constant nature of (at least) sensible things.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking further context, I would interpret this as:
All sensible things have a nature (that is to say, a set of properties or qualities, or a 'character' or 'basic constitution'); that nature is fixed and constant.